# Unble to run 'expo start' command after installed "@react-navigation/web"

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules

Getting below error in the terminal after installed  "@react-navigation/web" node module and Not able to start expo

**Error** :  **Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?**

```
├─ action /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:34:11
    ├─ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:135:22
    └─ expo start /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:350:7
```

Comment: run `npm install`

Comment: I already done with npm install

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 4):

Look for your Expo version in your **package.json**. I don't know why, but my version of Expo was 1.0.0, I changed it to the most recent one, which is 41.0.1 and it went back to work.

```
"expo": "~41.0.1",
```

Answer (score 2):

This Problem is Occurred Because of the Expo SDK version . so to solve this Follow the bellow Method:

1st Run this Command :

```
sudo npm install --global expo-cli
```

Enter Password to proceed
then run

```
sudo expo update
```

Now Run

```
expo start
```